# How to keep the wedding betrothal to Elaena Glenmore in episode 2 of Game of Throne?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of episode 2 "The Lost Lords", my choices show that I lost the betrothal to Elaena Glenmore. I did not forge the letter at the beginning, so I wonder: Was the letter forging a requirement? Or could I have saved the betrothal by certain choices alone during the conversation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to keep the betrothal:

- If, as Mira, you forged the letter from Margery, Elaena will tell you about the letter. When she says she feels she's being forced to marry you, tell her it's her choice. She'll say yes.
- If Mira didn't forge the letter, tell Elaena that you can pay her father in ironwood. She'll accept, in exchange for half the ironwood.

Answer (score 2):

It's [said in a thread](http://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/90804/game-of-thrones-episode-2-the-lost-lords-choices) that the option to offer offer ironwood keeps the betrothal even without forging the letter.